# How this DMA driver is not working in beaglebone black

Tags: linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, dma

I am trying to learn how DMA works in Linux kernel, and for that I have taken reference from this driver,

[dma_test.c](https://github.com/maciejjo/beaglebone-pru-dma/blob/master/wip/dma_test/kmod/dma_test.c)

I have inserted device tree entry for this inside [am33xx-l4.dtsi](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.179/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/am33xx-l4.dtsi#L1360) as below,

```dts
        target-module@60000 {           /* 0x48060000, ap 36 0c.0 */
            compatible = "ti,sysc-omap2", "ti,sysc";
            reg = <0x602fc 0x4>,
                  <0x60110 0x4>,
                  <0x60114 0x4>;
            reg-names = "rev", "sysc", "syss";
            ti,sysc-mask = <(SYSC_OMAP2_CLOCKACTIVITY |
                     SYSC_OMAP2_ENAWAKEUP |
                     SYSC_OMAP2_SOFTRESET |
                     SYSC_OMAP2_AUTOIDLE)>;
            ti,sysc-sidle = <SYSC_IDLE_FORCE>,
                    <SYSC_IDLE_NO>,
                    <SYSC_IDLE_SMART>;
            ti,syss-mask = <1>;
            /* Domains (P, C): per_pwrdm, l4ls_clkdm */
            clocks = <&l4ls_clkctrl AM3_L4LS_MMC1_CLKCTRL 0>;
            clock-names = "fck";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges = <0x0 0x60000 0x1000>;

            mmc1: mmc@0 {
                compatible = "ti,am335-sdhci";
                ti,needs-special-reset;
                dmas = <&edma_xbar 24 0 0
                    &edma_xbar 25 0 0>;
                dma-names = "tx", "rx";
                interrupts = <64>;
                reg = <0x0 0x1000>;
                status = "disabled";
            };
+
+           dmatest: dmatest@0 {
+               compatible = "dma-test";
+               dmas = <&edma 20 0>;
+               dma-names = "test_chan";
+               status = "ok";
+           };
        };
```

after this whenever I load the driver I get below error,

```
# insmod dma_module.ko 
[   74.453811] dma_test 480602fc.target-module:dmatest@0: Start probe
[   74.460323] dma_test 480602fc.target-module:dmatest@0: Configure dma xfer
[   74.472296] edma 49000000.dma: Exceeded max max_burst
[   74.479823] edma 49000000.dma: cfg->src_maxburst 1, chan->device->max_burst: 0
[   74.489582] edma 49000000.dma: cfg->dst_maxburst 1, chan->device->max_burst: 0
[   74.499283] dma_test 480602fc.target-module:dmatest@0: Dmaengine slave config failed
[   74.509742] dma_test: probe of 480602fc.target-module:dmatest@0 failed with error -22
# 
#
```

This error is coming from below snippet of code,

```c
    dmatest->dma_ch = dma_request_chan(dmatest->dev, "test_chan");
    if (IS_ERR(dmatest->dma_ch)) {
        ret = PTR_ERR(dmatest->dma_ch);
        dev_err(dmatest->dev, "Dma request channel failed");
        goto err;
    }

    memset(&cfg, 0, sizeof(cfg));

    cfg.src_addr = dmatest->buf_src_dma;
    cfg.dst_addr = dmatest->buf_dst_dma;
    cfg.src_addr_width = DMA_SLAVE_BUSWIDTH_4_BYTES;
    cfg.dst_addr_width = DMA_SLAVE_BUSWIDTH_4_BYTES;
    cfg.src_maxburst = 16;
    cfg.dst_maxburst = 16;

    ret = dmaengine_slave_config(dmatest->dma_ch, &cfg);
    if (ret) {
        dev_err(dmatest->dev, "Dmaengine slave config failed"); //<<--------------
        goto err_chan;
    }
```

I am not able to undestand why **chan->device->max_burst is 0**.
e.g. For mmc I get below logs,

```
[ 5535.195137] edma 49000000.dma: cfg->src_maxburst 128, chan->device->max_burst: 32767
[ 5535.202932] edma 49000000.dma: cfg->dst_maxburst 128, chan->device->max_burst: 32767
```

And this value **32767** is set inside edma.c file as, [edma.c#L2017](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.179/source/drivers/dma/ti/edma.c#L2017)

`s_ddev->max_burst = SZ_32K - 1;`

Kindly help and guide here, why **dmaengine_slave_config** is failing.

Comment: Do you know the difference between m2m and p2m/m2p type of DMA connections? From there the obvious questions are: “why do you ignore crossbar?”, and “are you sure the channel #20 of eDMA supports m2m?"

Comment: I have idea about dma channel and also about that these channels might be tied to specific hw module. I trusted the driver given by github link as these guys submitted it to GSOC. But yes when it comes to cross verify dma channel vs hw module, I am not able to check that in the reference manual, https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf?ts=1696840373289&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Regarding crossbar, I just started learning about it after your comment.